# How to select unmaintained Font Awesome Symbols?

Tags: fontawesome

The current [fontawesome](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome) package is not yet updated to the version 3.2.1 of [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). I'd like to manually select some of the new icons. Merging some snippets i have come up with this:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\def\faTwitterBird{{\FA \symbol{"F099}}}
\def\faCalender{{\FA \symbol{"F133}}}
\def\faXing{{\FA \symbol{"F168}}}

\begin{document}
- \faTwitterBird - \faCalender - \faXing
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it does not display one of the newer icons (e.g. xing).

[image]

Comment: Are you sure luatex actually finds the new font? Btw: I think the closing quote in the symbol command is wrong (The starting quote are tells latex that a hex number follows).

Comment: You're right. It was not loading my system font but from the installed package `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.otf`. Replacing this one yields the wanted result. Is there actually a better way to load the system font instead of replacing it in the package?

Comment: Imho the current luaotfload should prefer system fonts over texmf fonts. Did you rebuild the database with luaotfload-tool after installing the system font?

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by the new font file not being found by TeX.